# About tense in indirect speech

Tags: tense

> 1. I (Chinese Premire) was asked in 2016 whether there **will** be significant change in China-US ties when a new president **is** elected.
> 2. I (Chinese Premire) was asked in 2016 whether there **would** be significant change in China-US ties when a new president **was** elected .

This was a line said by Chinese Premire Li Keqiang when he recalled what had happened in 2016. I was wondering which tense usage is appropriate.

Comment: Both are "valid", but possible *implications* are a little more complicated. If we suppose Li Keqiang's English is *really* good, political analysts might suppose #1 more strongly implies the election result (and its possible effect on China-US relationships) is a *current, ongoing* development, whereas the "backshifting" of version #2 implies both the election *and* its effects are now definitely *things that **have** happened*, so they can be analysed. Since the Chinese think it's "still too early to say" whether the French Revolution was a Good Thing or not, #1 is probably more appropriate.

Comment: So what followed by "I [was]" can be any tenses, without having to be in the past tense as "I was" did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When he was asked, the question would be likely phrased, in English, "**will** there be significant change in China-US ties **when** a new president **is** elected?" This is because it is inevitable that a new president will be elected, and is asking "when this thing we are sure will happen happens, will this other thing happen?".

If it were something that was uncertain (such as if it were referring to a specific presidential election where the incumbent was standing for re-election), it would be "**would** there be significant change in China-US ties **were** a new president **to be** elected?" (or other phrasing changing the word order, such as putting the predicate first). Because English is flexible (which is to say, no-one agrees on every aspect of grammar), that 'would' can be replaced by 'will' without it seeming like the person can't speak English, though in that case the predicate would also often become "**if** a new President **is** elected", or "**should** a new president **be** elected". Strict grammarians can get rather tied up in knots trying to get people to speak in the way they consider correct.

Referring back to the question in the future, your second option would generally be considered acceptable, whether or not a new president has, since the question was originally asked, been elected. If that hasn't yet happened, the first would also be acceptable. If it has happened, then the first would seem very strange.

Oh, and you can also replace the 'when's with 'if's, and if you do, you can replace **is**/**was** with "were to be", whatever has happened since the question was originally asked.

Comment: What the question raiser said at that time in the past could be: 1) "will there be significant change in China-US ties when a new president is elected?" 2)"would there be significant change in China-US ties were a new president to be elected" 3)"will there be significant change in China-US ties should a new president is elected. However, I want to know how can we talke this in written English, turing the interrogative sentence  into declarative sentense, and more importantly, the predicate has changed to "I [was] asked" instead of "I [am]" asked,

Comment: should eveything followed by "I [was]" need to be in the past tense?

Comment: @MikePhilip: No. The verb tense issues here are just the same with ***He said X*** as they are with ***He was asked if X***, so you should think about examples like ***He said he will retire in 2020***. It's quite natural (but not necessarily *required*) to "backshift" that to ***He said he would retire in 2020***. All you need to understand is that you *must* backshift if you're speaking ***after*** 31st Dec 2020, OR if he has ***already retired*** when you make this statement.